# Convert video after upload

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am running a service where people can upload videos. Because of the large file sizes I would like to convert those videos after uploading.

I want it so that when the upload is done, a PHP script is called in which the video gets converted (using FFMPEG). When the conversion is done, the user receives a notification that the video is ready to use.

I am thinking of a separate PHP script that uses the path sent in POST. It will then call the FFMPEG line within shell_exec(). But how can I get it to run in the background and send a notification to the user when the process is done?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement some queue mechanic. For example, first script interacts with user, uploads file and insert new job into queue. The second script is started as the background server process every minute by scheduler (crontab in Linux, Task Scheduler in Windows). If the queue is not empty, background script receives the oldest job from queue and runs ffmpeg. When ffmpeg finished work and shell_exec returns control, you should mark this job as "ready". The easiest way to implement such queue is simple DB table or you can use special designed queue manager, e.g. RabbitMQ.

Also it good idea to write the third script to check job status and call it from user-interface with AJAX every X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a system similar to what Vladislav describes.  I use this [task spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/) to run my ffmpeg jobs, 2 at a time (modify depending on your hardware).  If you don't set up a queue you could end up trying to transcode dozens or hundreds of clips at the same time, bringing down your server.  Leave some threads open for your web service.  I wrote a PHP file (checked via ajax) that invokes a shell script that gives the user feedback, where there are in the queue etc.  Here's the business end of the bash shell script.

```
STATUS=$(ts | grep $NEWNAME | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "$STATUS" = "running" ] || [ "$STATUS" = "finished" ]; then
        CURRID=$(ts | grep $NEWNAME | awk '{print $1}')
        PID=$(ts -p $CURRID)
        echo "p$PID"
        exit 0
elif [ "$STATUS" = "queued" ]; then
        RUNNINGID=$(ts | grep running | awk '{print $1}')
        CURRID=$(ts | grep $NEWNAME | awk '{print $1}')
        LASTQ=$(ts | grep queued | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')
        ALLQ=$(($LASTQ-$RUNNINGID))
        LEFT=$(($CURRID-$RUNNINGID))
        echo "q$LEFT.$ALLQ"
        exit 0
else
        echo "done"
fi
```